# TYPO3 Neos: Apply content property run in JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, typoscript, typo3-flow, neoscms

I try to create a custom node type like the multi columns and the default `ContentCollection` should be extended with an additionaly property. The backend and frontend view works so far. But if the property `span` of the `ContentCollection` is changed, the editor run in a JavaScript timeout error. There are no error or warnings in the console.

The error message:

> Warning: Not answering Script
>
> Ein Skript auf dieser Seite ist eventuell beschäftigt oder es
>   antwortet nicht mehr. Sie können das Skript jetzt stoppen, im Debugger
>   öffnen oder weiter ausführen.
>
> Skript:
>   http://domain.com/_Resources/Static/Packages/TYPO3.Neos/JavaScript/ContentModule-built.js:389

To reproduce do following:

Using the site package "TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org". TYPO3 Neos v1.1.2.
Create an package "Selector.Test"

Configuration/Settings.yaml

```
TYPO3:
  Neos:

    typoScript:
      autoInclude:
        'Selector.Test': TRUE

    nodeTypes:
      groups:
        selectorTest:
          label: 'Selector Test'
          position: 10
```

Configuration/NodeTypes.Columns.yaml

```
'Selector.Test:RowAbstract':
  abstract: TRUE
  superTypes:
    - 'TYPO3.Neos:Content'
  ui:
    label: 'Columns'
    group: 'selectorTest'
    icon: 'icon-columns'
    inlineEditable: TRUE
    inspector:
      groups:
        columnSettings:
          label: 'Column settings'
          position: 10

# Create a custom ContentCollection
'Selector.Test:ColumnContentCollection':
  superTypes:
    - 'TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection'
  ui:
    label: 'Column Content Collection'
    icon: 'icon-list'
    inlineEditable: TRUE
    inspector:
      groups:
        columnSpan:
          label: 'Column span'
          position: 10
  properties:
    span:
      type: string
      defaultValue: ''
      ui:
        label: 'Span'
        reloadIfChanged: TRUE
        inspector:
          group: 'columnSpan'

# Define row with custom ContentCollection
'Selector.Test:Row':
  superTypes:
    - 'Selector.Test:RowAbstract'
  childNodes:
    column0:
      type: 'Selector.Test:ColumnContentCollection'
    column1:
      type: 'Selector.Test:ColumnContentCollection'
```

Resources/Private/TypoScript/Root.ts2

```
prototype(Selector.Test:Row) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Content) {

    templatePath = 'resource://Selector.Test/Private/Templates/NodeTypes/Row.html'

    attributes {
        class = 'row'
    }

    columns = TYPO3.TypoScript:Collection {
        collection = ${q(node).children('[instanceof TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection]')}
        itemRenderer = Selector.Test:Column
        itemName = 'node'
    }
}

prototype(Selector.Test:Column) < prototype(TYPO3.TypoScript:Template) {

    node = ${node}
    templatePath = 'resource://Selector.Test/Private/Templates/NodeTypes/Column.html'

    attributes = TYPO3.TypoScript:Attributes {
        class.span = ${q(node).property('span') ? q(node).property('span') : null}
    }

    columnContentCollection = TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection {
        nodePath = '.'
    }
}
```

Resources/Private/Templates/NodeTypes/Column.html

```
{namespace ts=TYPO3\TypoScript\ViewHelpers}
<div{attributes -> f:format.raw()}>
    <ts:render path="columnContentCollection" />
</div>
```

Resources/Private/Templates/NodeTypes/Row.html

```
{namespace ts=TYPO3\TypoScript\ViewHelpers}
<div{attributes -> f:format.raw()}>
    <ts:render path="columns" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem described in [this Jira issue](https://jira.typo3.org/browse/NEOS-188). Unfortunately it was not solved yet, but a preliminary solution exists as an open change (for review): https://review.typo3.org/#/c/31244/

You could try to apply that change to the TYPO3.Neos package and give feedback if it solves your problem, so it can be incorporated in the next Neos release.

Comment: I tried this patch about one week ago in v1.1.2 and v1.2-beta, but it don't solves the problem. In the meanwhile I use another methode and don't need it anymore. But for the future it can be useful, I think.